# ScrollEvent on my scene

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar

I corrected my code and now it works with the mouse's scroll, but I only can scroll down. It happens because I have setted "val += sb.getUnitIncrement()" so I thought to insert a condition to detect if I scroll up or down and if I scroll up "val -= sb.unitIncrement()". The problem is that I wasn't able to find that method. What should I use?

```
private double val = 0;

@FXML
private Button back;

@FXML
private AnchorPane Instructions;

@FXML
private ImageView image;

@FXML
private ScrollBar sb;


private void scroll() {
    sb.sceneProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Scene> observable, Scene oldValue, Scene newValue) -> {
        if (newValue != null) {
            sb.getScene().setOnScroll((ScrollEvent event) -> {
                if (val < sb.getMax()) {
                    val += sb.getUnitIncrement();
                    image.setLayoutY(-val);
                    if (val < sb.getMax() - sb.getUnitIncrement()) {
                        back.setVisible(false);
                    } else if (val >= sb.getMax() - sb.getUnitIncrement()) {
                        back.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In `scroll()` you set the `setOnScroll` of the stage to invoke `moveImage() `on scroll. Then in `moveImage` you are adding a listener again and again and again ...

Comment: I've update the question

Comment: Wouldn't be it easier to put the image into a `ScrollPane` and let it do the job for you?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with DVarga, it's easier if you use a `ScrollPane`. Modify your FXML file, delete the `ScrollBar` and add a `ScrollPane`. Then try with this code:

```
@FXML
private ImageView image;

@FXML
private Button back;

@FXML
private AnchorPane Instructions;

@FXML
private ScrollPane sp;

private void setScrollPane() {
    sp.setContent(image);
    sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    sp.setFitToWidth(true);
    sp.setFitToHeight(true);
    sp.vvalueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val, Number new_val) -> {
        if (new_val.doubleValue() >= sp.getVmax()) {
            back.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (new_val.doubleValue() < sp.getVmax()) {
            back.setVisible(false);
        }
    });        
}
```

Because you were only using a vertical scroll bar, I suppose you don't need the horizontal bar and I also suppose you want your button visible at the end of your image.
Call the method on your `initialize()` method of your controller.